# AngularJS ng-repeat group by property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a collection of comments which I'm displaying in a view with a `ng-repeat` directive.

My comment object has a `.deleted` boolean property, which if set to true, will display a message like *This comment has been deleted*.

When more than one subsequent comment has `deleted: true`, I would like to display *# comments have been deleted*.

Is there a way to do this out of the box ? Or do I have to take care of that logic myself ?

Comment: You have to create that logic yourself.

Comment: Find a way to group related comments then use count filter in the view to count deleted comments while iterating them using ng-repeat

Comment: Thanks guys I'll try it out and post the answer if I succeed